# Fan off under 90°C

Tags: windows-7, fan, temperature

I have a new Samsung PC, model NP350V5C-S06FR.

It came with Win8, but I removed it and replaced with Ubuntu 13.04 & Windows 7.

**In Win7, the main fan does not turn on (i can't feel any air), unless CPU temperature reaches 90°C. In about 60 seconds, the CPU goes down from 90°C to 60°C.**

In Ubuntu, the fan seems to work normally. In BIOS, it also runs at max speed.

There are no BIOS settings for fan speed. Speedfan and similar software do not find my fan.

I'm pretty sure all the latest drivers are installed.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What BIOS is that? AMI? Afaik, Linux doesn't use the BIOS at all. Aren't there some Windows tools on the CD that came with the mainboard?

Comment: @ott-- I don't believe there was a CD. I don't know how to check for BIOS but it does indeed look like this : http://www.aoaforums.com/forum/attachments/hardware-hacking/22068d1202585058-award-vs-ami-bios-b_bios.jpg

Comment: Yes, that`s AMI. What's on the page with H/W Monitor?

Comment: @ott-- I don't have an H/W Monitor page. I went into BIOS and can confirm it's American Megatrends Inc, BIOS version PO2ABE, Aptio Setup Utility. The tabs I have access to are "SysInfo", "Advanced", "Security", "Boot", "Exit".

Comment: One last thing you could try: as the BIOS is rather old (2004), you could check if the mainboard manufactorer has released a newer version.

Comment: @ott-- I updated it to PO8ABE, and this seems to have fixed the problem. I say "seems" because i'm not sure this is the one thing that did the trick, but my cores happily now remain below 60°C

Converting this into an answer and how-to-fix.

Answer (score 3):

After calling Samsung tech support in France (this is, after all, a French edition laptop), I found out about the automatic updater for this computer, called "SW Update".

Here is a direct link : http://orcaservice.samsungmobile.com/SWUpdate.aspx

It can also be found on this page : http://www.samsung.com/fr/support/model/NP350V5C-S06FR-downloads?downloadName=BM-P
On the left side, under "SW Update".

Even though it says it's for Win8, the tech support guy told me it would work for Win7. It does. **I updated my BIOS from PO2ABE to PO8ABE.** This seems to have fixed my problem.

The fan now happily keeps my CPU cores cooled down below 50°C.

Thank you @Ott-- for the help.

NOTE : Updating the BIOS will also prevent you from booting if you, like me, removed the UEFI boot thingy. You'll have to disable the secure boot in BIOS and select "UEFI and Legacy OS".

Answer (score 0):

You an use [Speedan to override the temperature curve](http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5):

[image]

Comment: This is true and i personally use speedfan as well seeing as i have 7 fans in my case. However, i doubt that this will fix his problem in this case simply because his pc could not detect the fan so there will be no extra power going to the fan.

Comment: Indeed, @MarcoGeertsma, my Samsung laptop does not give Speedfan any access to its fans.